# Outside User isolation in google storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, user-controls, sts

Is there a way to isolate outside user who does not have account in GCP,(i am talking about the feature like STS credetials in AWS, which can be created by roles and policy for the user who does not belong to AWS). So is there a similar feature present in GCP?

I did some research but did not find anything.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Akhilesh Verma

Comment: Google Cloud does not need a service like STS. Google Cloud already uses OAuth tokens for access control. You can issue as many tokens as you want from your own code or the SDKs. Review how Google Cloud service accounts work.

Comment: Can you tell what's your goal ? The Question is not clear to me - please update your post.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?